# Expected value and variance of records

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence

Let $X_1,X_2...$ be an i.i.d. continuous random variables. We say a record occurs at time $n$ and we set $Y_n=1$ if $X_n>\max\left\{ X_{1},...,X_{n}\right\} $ and $Y_n=0$ in otherwise. Let $R_n=Y_1+...+Y_n$ be the number of records that have been set by time $n$. Find $\mathbb{E}\left[R_n\right]$ and $\mathbb{\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}}\left[R_n\right]$.

My solution:

$\mathbb{E}\left[R_n\right]=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$

$\mathbb{\mathbb{V}\mathrm{ar}}\left[R_n\right]=1(1-1)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+...++\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$

It's ok?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated right? Is the inequality really strict? It seems to me that $\forall n \in \mathbb N, Y_n = 0$ a.s.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by continuity we have $\omega \in \Omega$,

$$X_p(\omega) \ne X_q(\omega) \ \forall p \ne q$$

Define:

$$A_n:= (X_n > \max\{X_1, X_2, ... X_n\})$$

Observe that:

$$A_1:= (X_1 > \max\{X_1\}) = (X_1 > \max\{X_1\}) = \emptyset$$

$$A_2:= (X_2 > \max\{X_1, X_2\})$$

$$ = (X_2 > X_1) = \emptyset \ \text{if} \ (X_1 > X_2)$$

$$ = (X_2 > X_2) = \emptyset \ \text{if} \ (X_2 > X_1)$$

$$A_3:= (X_3 > \max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\})$$

$$ = (X_3 > X_1) = \emptyset \ \text{if} \ (X_1 > X_3)$$

$$ = (X_3 > X_2) = \emptyset \ \text{if} \ (X_2 > X_3)$$

$$ = (X_3 > X_3) = \emptyset \ \text{if} \ (X_3 > X_1, X_2)$$

$$\vdots$$

Thus, $$Y_n = 1_{A_n} = 1_{\emptyset} = 0$$

Hence, $$E[Y_n] = Var[Y_n] = Y_n = 0 = E[Y_n^k] \ \forall k \ge 2$$

---

However, if the inequality is NOT strict i.e.

$$Y_n = 1_{B_n}$$

where

$$B_n:= (X_n \ge \max\{X_1, X_2, ... X_n\}) = (X_n = \max\{X_1, X_2, ... X_n\})$$

Then you are right because

1. $P(B_n)= 1/n$ ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539690/prove-symmetry-of-probabilities-given-random-variables-are-iid-and-have-continuo))
2. $B_n$'s are [independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548257/) (needed in computing variance).

Consider

$B_2 = \{X_2 = \max\{X_1, X_2\}\}$

$B_3 = \{X_3 = \max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}\}$

Since the $X_n$'s are independent, the probability that $X_3$ is the maximum among $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is independent of which is the maximum among $X_1, X_2$

Comment: I have similar problem. Let $\pi$ be a permutation which is uniformly chosen from a set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. We define a record $\pi(k)$ which fulfills the condition $\pi(k)>\pi(j)$ for $j=1,2,\ldots, k-1$. I guess the reasoning in my case will be the same as above when I want to count expected value and variation. But what about evaluating probablility $P(A_k)$ where $A_k$ is an event which assumes that $\pi(k)$ is a record? I kindly ask to tell if I am right and to any advices with evaluating $P(A_k)$.