# Probability of the record, its expected value and variation

Tags: probability, permutations, expected-value, variance

I have a problem with evaluating the probability $P(A_k)$, where $A_k$ is a probability of the event that $\pi(k)$ is a record and $\pi$ is uniformly chosen random permutation from a set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Record occurs when $\pi(k)>\pi(j)$ for $j=1, \ldots, k-1$. We can see that
$$P(A_k)=P(\pi(k)>\pi(j), j=1, \ldots, k-1)$$
so I think the probability will be equal to $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}$, in particular we have $P(A_1)=1$, $P(A_2)=\dfrac{1}{2} $, etc. Is this correct? 
My second question corresponds to evaluation of $EX_n$ and $VarX_n$ where $X_n$ is an amount of records. I have found something connected here [Expected value and variance of records](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541254/expected-value-and-variance-of-records), but I'm not sure if it is right in my case. 
Thanks for all advices and help in advance.

Comment: If you have a randomly sorted  list of $k$ distinct numbers, the greatest is equally likely to be in any slot.  Thus the probability that the greatest one is the last one is $\frac 1k$.

Comment: Should say: your method, that yields $\left(\frac 12\right)^{k-1}$, is incorrect because it wrongly assumes independence.  If I know that $a_k>a_1$ and $a_k>a_2$, say, that is evidence that $a_k$ is large which changes the estimate of $P(a_k>a_3)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what about expected value and variation? Is it equal to zero like it is evaluated in a link I mentioned?

Comment: How could the expected number of records be $0$?  You already noted that the first entry is (trivially) a record so you know $X_n≥1$ for all permutations.

Comment: Why not try to work some examples?  That's always a good idea.  Try $n=3$, say.

Comment: Yes, that wasn't rational. So for $n=3$ we have $EX_3=1\cdot1+2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+3\cdot\frac{1}{3}$. Right?

Comment: For $n=3$ there is no reason not to simply list all $6$ permutations and do the count explicitly.  Your answer, $3$, is, again, obviously wrong.  The only permutation with three records is $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: Could you explain how should it look like in general case? Unfortunately I don't understand.

Comment: Please try to work some examples.  Just guessing at the pattern isn't working for you.

Comment: I will use the definition of expected value: $EX=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_ip_i$. We can notice that $p_1=\frac{1}{1}, p_2=\frac{1}{2!},p_3=\frac{1}{3!}$ etc. So $EX_3=1\cdot1+2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+3\cdot\frac{1}{6}=2\frac{1}{2}$. Maybe this time I'm right.

Comment: As I said, guessing is a waste of time.  Working examples is always a good idea...I don't know why you are so reluctant to do that.  Both $n=3$ and $n=4$ can be done by hand.  (there are already $120$ permutations for $n=5$ so that may be out of  reach).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to evaluate the expected value, so I'm publishing the solution if someone would be interested.
We have
$EX_1=x_1p_1=1\cdot\frac{1}{1!}=1,$ 
$EX_2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2}x_ip_i=1\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+2\cdot\frac{1}{2!}=1\frac{1}{2},$
$EX_3=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}x_ip_i=1\cdot\frac{2}{3!}+2\cdot\frac{3}{3!}+3\cdot\frac{1}{3!}=1\frac{5}{6},$ 
$EX_4=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{4}x_ip_i=1\cdot\frac{6}{4!}+2\cdot\frac{14}{4!}+3\cdot\frac{3}{4!}+4\cdot\frac{1}{4!}=1\frac{23}{24}.$ 
So as we can see $EX_n=1\frac{n!-1}{n!}$ which may be easily proven by method of induction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply the solution from [Expected value and variance of records](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541254/expected-value-and-variance-of-records). Let's take a closer look.
Let $A_k=1$ if $\pi(k)$ is a record and $A_k=0$ else.
It holds
$$P(A_k=1)=P(\pi(k)=\max(\pi(1),\dots,\pi(k)))=\frac{1}{k}$$
and therefore
$$P(A_k=0)=\frac{k-1}{k}.$$
For any $k$ we have
$$EA_k=0\cdot P(A_k=0)+1\cdot P(A_k=1)=\frac1k.$$
With $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^nA_k$ we have
$$EX_n=\sum_{k=1}^nEA_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k.$$
Let's now look at the Variance.
\begin{align*}\operatorname{Var}(A_k)&=(0-EA_k)^2\cdot P(A_k=0)+(1-EA_k)^2\cdot P(A_k=1)\\&=\frac{1}{k^2}\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}+\left(1-\frac1k\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{k}\\&=\frac{k-1}{k^3}+\frac{(k-1)^2}{k^3}\\&=\frac{k-1}{k^2}\\&=\frac1k\left(1-\frac1k\right)\end{align*}
and therefore we have
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\left(1-\frac1k\right).$$