# Strange $n$-dimensional volume integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

The following integral came up in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578824/):

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{x}\int\limits_{0}^{2x-x_1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{nx-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{n-1}}\mathrm dx_{n} \ldots \mathrm dx_1 $$

where $x>0$ is a real number and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How should one go about this? Trying successive integration gets messy quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relates to something called the parking function.  I would say the iterated integral is always equal to

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{x}\int\limits_{0}^{2x-x_1}\ldots\int\limits_{0}^{nx-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{n-1}}\mathrm dx_{n} \ldots \mathrm dx_1  = \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n!}.x^n$$

Goodluck